# My libevent timer stops as soon as another event occurs... is that normal?

Tags: c++, timer, libevent

Currently I setup two events:

- Listen for new connections from clients (I'm a server)
- A timer to run some code once a second to do various background work

On startup the timer works and I can wait as long as I want and my callback gets called over and over again every second just as expected.

However, as soon as I get a client connection, the other even occurs, and somehow the timer stops working. Is there a known bug in the libevent interface or am I possibly misusing the library?

*I am using libevent version libevent-2.0-5:amd64 under Ubuntu 14.04.*

*I added my own C++ interface so showing all the code here would be really large. It can be browsed in the project on SourceForge.net here:*

https://sourceforge.net/p/snapcpp/code/ci/master/tree/snapwebsites/lib/snap_communicator.h
https://sourceforge.net/p/snapcpp/code/ci/master/tree/snapwebsites/lib/snap_communicator.cpp

The usage is pretty simple, but again it is pretty large, the complete implementation is found here:

https://sourceforge.net/p/snapcpp/code/ci/master/tree/snapwebsites/lib/snapwebsites.cpp

The important part looks like this:

```
g_connection = new connection_t;
g_connection->f_communicator.reset(new snap_communicator(priority));

g_connection->f_listener.reset(new listener_impl(this, host[0].toUtf8().data(), p, max_pending_connections, true, false));
g_connection->f_listener->set_name("server listener");
g_connection->f_communicator->add_connection(g_connection->f_listener);

g_connection->f_temporary_timer.reset(new temporary_timer(this));
g_connection->f_temporary_timer->set_name("server timer");
g_connection->f_communicator->add_connection(g_connection->f_temporary_timer);

g_connection->f_communicator->run();
```

As we can see I add those two "connections" and the timer works just fine until the listener happens. There is only one place where I remove those two connections from the libevent objects and it is NOT hit (I would know I have a log, and yes, the logger works just fine.)

Answer (score 2):

My mistake! The documentation clearly says that you should make your sockets non-blocking. Once I did that, it started working as expected.

My socket was blocking before since I was just calling `accept()`...

Now I really don't understand why the library has such a limitation, but that was the solution to this question.

I added the following code for the listener:

```
if(get_socket() != -1)
{
    // libevent does not like blocking sockets...
    int optval(1);
    ioctl(get_socket(), FIONBIO, &optval);
}
```